# Smart Contract Deployment Stays in Pending State

Tags: contract-deployment

Pretty straight-forward problem. I'm trying to deploy a smart contract token using Mist (not the browser). When I click deploy, it asks me to confirm, tells me the gas it'll use (maybe that's too low? Currently it's at 8) and then I confirm and it just stays in pending state. I've tried to deploy it 3 times now with increasing gas. What could be the problem? The current max amount of ETH to spend is .016, that's quite a bit and it still isn't confirming.

Answer (score 1):

The pending state for the transaction may not being going through because:

- you are not currently mining or connected to a mining node.
- the gas price is set too high.
- you may be inadvertently increasing the gas price each time you attempt to deploy.
- your account hasn't been unlocked or the transaction wasn't signed.

If you can provide more information about which chain/network you are using that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was a Mist problem. I couldn't send ETH out either and the blocks would freeze after Mist was running for about 10 minutes. I used withpragma.com to deploy it instead using metamask